# Url helper with GET parameter in laravel

Tags: url, laravel-4

I want to create an url with this format :

```
domain.com/list?sortBy=number&sortDir=desc
```

in my View (blade). I'm using this approach which I don't really prefered :

```
{{ url("list")."?sortBy=".$sortBy."&sortDir=".$sortDir }}
```

because using

```
{{ url("list", $parameters = array('sortBy' => $sortBy, 'sortDir' => $sortDir) }}
```

didn't produce as I hoped. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `URL::route` method.

Example Route:

```
Route::get('/list', array('as' => 'list.index', 'uses' => 'ListController@getIndex'));
```

Retrieve the URL to a specific route with query string:

```
URL::route('list.index', array(
  'sortBy' => $sortBy,
  'sortDir' => $sortDir
));
```

If your using a closure on the route:

```
Route::get('/list', array('as' => 'list.index', function()
{
    return URL::route('account-home', array(
       'sortBy' => 1,
       'sortDir' => 2
    ));
}));
```

Comment: how to use it without controller? I'm using a closure